# Colorscheme's background not correct in terminal

Tags: vimrc, terminal, colorscheme, x11

I imported the solarized colorscheme and palette. My terminal has the correct colors and background, gvim has the correct colors and background, but vim has an incorrectly colored background. The text is all correct, but the background appears to be pure black.

[image: This is a comparison of Terminal, GVim, and Vim]

Here is my .vimrc:

```
syntax enable

if has('gui_running')
    set background=dark
else
    set background=dark
endif

:set t_Co=256
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
```

If anyone has any suggestions on what could be causing this, I would be much obliged. I run xubuntu with the default terminal.

I should also mention that the light option results in a very yellow background for Vim.

Comment: By "[m]y terminal has the correct colors and background," do you mean to say that you followed the [specific advice](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) regarding Vim in the terminal?

Comment: I did follow the advice, @Andrew. Thank you though.

Comment: @Oberdiear The advice Andrew links to explains that you should set up your terminal to use solarized colours, and *not* use  the `g:solarized_termcolors=256` option. If you're happy to use solarized colours in your terminal, this method works much better. The text of your question implies you *have* set up your terminal to use solarized colours (although the screenshot you display doesn't look to me like it does), so in that case, why are you using the `g:solarized_termcolors=256` setting?

Comment: What terminal are you using? I have [this script](https://gist.github.com/WChargin/d2ab9805b0f2d5e51845) for `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: @Rich, I guess that I don't have the palette set up correctly. Do you (or someone else) know how to correctly set that up for Xfce Terminal?

Comment: @Oberdiear You could try this: https://github.com/sgerrand/xfce4-terminal-colors-solarized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great news, everyone. @Tom and @Rich set me on the right path. I found a solution provided [here](https://github.com/sgerrand/xfce4-terminal-colors-solarized). I set my .vimrc to the simple

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
set t_Co=16
colorscheme solarized
```

This seems to fix everything. The colors don't seem to be as bright in the [font examples](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/img/terminus12), but that could very well just be me. To anyone who wants to use the Solarized colorscheme and uses xfce4-terminal, just changing the terminalrc and the .vimrc seemed to solve my main problems. Thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't need the `set t_Co` line in your vimrc: Vim can read this value from the terminal (Setting `'t_Co'` seems to be a bit of a Vim cargo cult: lots of people online recommend doing so without really understanding the issues they're attempting to solve.)

Comment: I'll just say "screen" and "tmux" - these tools change the $TERM variable so vim can't read the information it needs.

Comment: @NieDzejkob You can use a terminal multiplexer and still have a correctly-configured terminal.

Comment: @Rich do you mind explaining what the right fix on the terminal side is? I'm using tmux with `$TERM=screen` and setting `t_Co=16` does indeed fix visual issues for me, but I'd like to know what the relationship is, in the first place.

Comment: @ffledgling I'd love to. Might require a bit of back and forth, though, so [come join me in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104132/t-co-vs-termcap).

Answer (score 10):

There's two reasons why I think this may be happening:

1. The solarized color scheme you are using does not declare `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` for any of the features you want to highlight. Try out this [color scheme](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1243), should look essentially the same both inside your terminal and gvim, if this is the case then you may need to look into using a color scheme that declares `ctermfg` and `ctermbg`.
2. You may need to make sure your terminal emulator supports the colors you are trying to display:

   - Ensure that the file [`ncurses-term` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ncurses-term&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) (which provides the file `/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm+256color`) is installed.
   - [Set the value of your `TERM` environment variable](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim) by running

     ```
     export TERM=xterm+256colors
     ```

     at the shell.
   - Then start `vim` in that shell.

---

Note that both of this things could be happening at the same time, but it is hard to diagnose this without more information about your system.

Comment: The desert256 works fine, but I am not a huge fan. I do believe the `TERM` variable is incorrect, but I have no idea how to change it.

Comment: I installed ncurses-term. I then ran the command. After I run it, all text becomes grey and the background is black.

Comment: It should be `export TERM=xterm+256color`, NOT "color**s**" (plural).
Also, I believe that is should be `xterm-256color`, NOT "**+**256color; but I may be wrong specifically about using it with solarized.
According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/744948/term-xterm-256color-vs-xterm256color), `# Entries with embedded plus signs are designed to be included through use/tc capabilities, not used as standalone entries.`

Comment: `export TERM=xterm+256color` on OSX I get `zle-line-finish:echoti:1: no such terminfo capability: rmkx`

Comment: I had this exact issue and `export TERM=xterm+256colors` helped vim solarized detect and use the exact background color as what my terminal has.

Comment: Yes, it is `export TERM=xterm-256color`. Value `xterm-256color` for 256-bit color, `xterm` for 8-bit. When vim see the former value, it should set `t_Co=256`. If leaving `TERM=xterm` and in vim doing `:set t_Co=256` will still give poor color.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is an issue of compatibility of this `colorscheme` with terminal.
The plugin `csaprox` miraculously solve a bunch of this issues.

Synopsis:

> It's hard to find colorschemes for terminal Vim.  Most colorschemes are 
>   written to only support GVim, and don't work at all in terminal Vim.
>
> This plugin makes GVim-only colorschemes Just Work in terminal Vim, as long 
>   as the terminal supports 88 or 256 colors - and most do these days.  This 
>   usually requires no user interaction (but see the help for what to do if 
>   things don't Just Work).  After getting this plugin happily installed, any 
>   time you use `:colorscheme` it will do its magic and make the colorscheme Just 
>   Work.

Links to the plugin:

- [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390)
- [Github](https://github.com/godlygeek/csapprox)

Comment: This is a useful plugin, but won't help here, as the solarized colorscheme already goes to considerable effort to work in terminal Vim under both 16-color and 256-color terminals.

Answer (score 4):

The solarized terminal-Vim colorscheme can work in one of two different ways.

1. A 16-colour mode: Solarized only contains 16 colours, so in this mode you set your *terminal* to use the solarized colours as its 16 colours, and the Vim colorscheme just uses these. So for example, the Vim colorscheme will request terminal colour "1", and the terminal displays this as the hex colour #dc322f.
2. A 256-colour mode, where it picks the closest matches for its 16 colours from a 256-color palette.

The former method is [strongly recommended by the author](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) (and by me), and it sounds as though you are happy to use this method because you state that your "terminal has the correct colors and background".

However, it appears from your screenshot that your terminal does *not* have the correct colours set. (White is not a colour in the solarized set, and although I haven't eyedroppered it, the other text colour in the screenshot doesn't look to me like it's Solarized "Violet" (#6c71c4), either.)

If you remove the lines setting `t_Co` and `g:solarized_termcolors` from your vimrc*, and configure your terminal colours correctly, then you should find that the 16-colour solarized colorscheme will start to work.

<sub>* These lines switch solarized to using its (less faithful) 256-colour mode. This should also work, (I suspect that [@Jubal is correct in suggesting that BCE is the problem here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2058/343)), but the 16-colour mode is preferable unless you explicitly *don't* want to use solarized in your terminal.</sub>

Comment: I believe you are completely on the right track. I think I don't have the palette installed correctly. Could you walk me through the process? I appreciate all your help, @Rich.

Comment: It appears your first link is now dead.

Comment: @azoki Thanks for letting me know. Looks like the Solarized site is under (re)construction. I changed the link to point into the github repo for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you found your answer. I had this same problem and nothing above worked. What worked for me was using [altercation's `terminalrc`](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/xfce4-terminal/dark/terminalrc), as opposed to [sgerrand's](https://github.com/sgerrand/xfce4-terminal-colors-solarized/blob/master/dark/terminalrc).

My relevant `vimrc` is simply:

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

So this is what works for me (on all terminals I used to use – xterm, konsole, gnome-terminal, iterm2, roxterm – on both Linux and OS X, also with gvim and macvim):

```
" no other configuration than this needed for solarized
colorscheme solarized
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=11 ctermbg=8

if &term =~ '256color'
  " Disable Background Color Erase (BCE) so that color schemes work
  " properly within 256-color terminals
  set t_ut=
endif
```

Comment: This caused a similar problem to setting t_Co=16. I'm fairly certain I have a problem with the palette, but I have yet to figure it out.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? If I recall correctly, konsole's built-in solarized configuration is not fully usable and one needs to use settings from the original solarized repository…

Comment: I use Xfce Terminal.

Comment: I think I got it working: try to force TERM to xterm-256color, while using the solarized preset from the terminal's preferences, not from the solarized xfce-terminal git repository.

This along with the BCE hack above did the trick for xfce4-terminal for me.

Comment: (There's still something fishy with the underlying terminal emulation _and_ font rendering, and I guess I got reminded why I went back to plain old xterm on Linux…)

Answer (score 0):

This was a pain to get working (I use terminal Vim in Linux Mint), and unfortunately I didn't write down the specifics of everything I did. Here is the relevant section of my vimrc:

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
set t_Co=16
colo solarized
```

It may also be worth checking out [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized).

Comment: set t_Co=16 causes the colors to be radically different from what is expected.
I am also using the default Xubuntu terminal is Xfce-Terminal.

Comment: @Oberdiear If setting t_Co=16 affects the colours in that way (with the g:solarized_termcolors variable unset) then that means that your terminal colours are not set up correctly to use solarized. How are you setting your terminal colours?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove this part of your settings

```
if has('gui_running')
   set background=dark
else
   set background=dark
endif
```

I am running a xfce4-terminal

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too with `xfce-terminal`.

After a bit of research, I discovered [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xfce4-terminal/+bug/778801): anything you set as `$TERM` in your XFCE terminal is silently ignored.

I think this is really a bug of the underlying (and unmaintained) [old VTE library](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/0.28/) that XFCE terminal (still GTK+2 based) uses. Switching to a GTK+3 terminal, that implicitely uses the [new VTE library](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/0.44/), solved the issue.