# vim expression unusual behavior

Tags: vimscript, functions

While playing with `map()` I get an error, which I cannot understand.

In essense,

```
pu=map(getcompletion('*','event'), '"h" . v:val')
pu=map(getcompletion('*','event'), "'h' . v:val")
pu=map(getcompletion('*','event'), {i,v -> "h" . v})
pu=map(getcompletion('*','event'), {i,v -> 'h' . v})
```

only last one works, all other raise error.

I thought it should all work, or it's just not correctly written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing here, is essentially the same problem, as why many people struggle with using variables on the command line with the ex commands. See e.g. [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2139), there are a lot similar ones.

Basically, Vims ex commandline commands expect their arguments to be literal, they cannot contain expressions (like variables or strings). Those commands do handle `%` and `#` (and a few others that I do not remember currently) special by replacing the former with the current filename and the latter by the alternate file name. At the same time, `"` is used to donate the start of a comment, everything after it will be ignored (not even seen by the command). The usage of `"` as a comment character goes back all the way to the original vi and therefore cannot be changed because this would introduce an incompatibility to the classic vi.

A few commands, that were not available in the original vi implementation, however are able to handle *expressions*. The help usually mentions whenever a command expects an expression instead of a (literal) argument. The most notable ex commands that do that are `:exe`, `:echo`, `:echomsg` and similar ex commands. That's why one has to use `:exe` to dynamically build ex commands (see e.g. [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21393/71) for a great explanation).

Those expressions can contain variables and strings, either single quoted or double quoted and therefore the `"` is not detected as the start of a comment there. However, `:put` is one of the old ex commands that was available already in old original vi. However adding the possibility to put an arbitrary expression using the expression register `=` has been added for Vim only. So while you can use any expression when using `:put=`, Vim will still parse the arguments for the `:put` comments and see `"` as a start of a comment and not as start of a string.

That is an implementation detail, that can still be seen today.

Note, the error message would have given you a hint:

[image: error message after executing above command]

That was me executing your 3rd example:

```
pu=map(getcompletion('*','event'), {i,v -> "h" . v})
```

See how the echoed command stops after the `->` and does not contain anything after the comment?

That's why you have to escape the `"` using e.g. `\"` on the command line for the `:put` command. So try to use this instead:

```
:pu =map(getcompletion('*','event'), {i,v -> \"h\" . v})
```

Comment: *"the `"` is seen as quote character"*, well it **is** a *quote* character. I think it would be clearer if you described it as "a *comment* character", which is the case in this context. Also, you mentioned escaping it with `\\"` but actually you only need a single backslash, `\"` is enough...

Comment: A reference to [`:help :comment`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Acomment) is useful here, as it helps explain why using double quotes for strings is fine in many contexts, but not here (I *guess* it's because it's using the `:put` command, which is not an exception for the comment semantics of double quotes... Correct?)

Comment: the `\\"` was just me fighting with markdown. Also the current answer is a bit over-simplified. Will update.

Comment: Awesome expansion!!! 